# Is there a free shell service for Mac computers?

Tags: macos, shell

I'm looking for a shell where I can test shellscripts and a programs on a Mac.

What I'm looking for, is something like [bshellz.net](http://bshellz.net) but with Apple computers (i.e. Macs). Is there such thing available?

I was googling for the last few days, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Can't you just use a virtual machine or something?

Comment: Not really, Try installing OS X in a VM, it won't work. Apple made sure you can OS X *only* on Apple hardware. I was unsuccessful installing OS in a VM (a virtualized Hackintosh, so to say).

Comment: OSX Server can be installed in VMWare as mentioned here: http://blogs.vmware.com/vmtn/2008/01/virtual-leopa-1.html

Comment: Those are very good reasons for a non-Apple-user to not develop for OS X.

Comment: @Jon Steinmetz: that VM runs on Apple hardware. I don't have apple hardware, as I've stated above. See the "Important thing to note" paragraph where they clearly say that this runs on genuine Apple hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing a free software (open source) project, you might be able to request access to the [GCC compile farm](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/CompileFarm), which appears to include at least one Mac Mini.

If you're not developing free software, it might be harder to find people willing to donate their CPU and bandwidth to you for free, especially since Mac hardware tends to be a bit expensive and Mac OS X is difficult to virtualize unless you pay half a grand for Mac OS X Server. There seem to be a variety of places which offer colo or dedicated hosting for Mac Minis and XServes, but not a lot of people providing free or cheap shell accounts on shared servers.

Comment: Sounds like the best option so far. Best thing would be running OS X in a VM, but as we know it, this is not allowed/possible.